# Latent profile analysis and Factor Analysis

Tags: multinomial-distribution, discriminant-analysis, latent-variable

How different is Latent Profile Analysis from Factor Analysis and what is the role of Multinomial Regression ? Does anybody have any intuitive ideas to understand the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, factor analysis (FA, intro [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/seminars/introduction-to-factor-analysis)) assumes continuous latent variable(s) while LPA (see intro [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001879120300701)) assumes discrete latent variables. In its way, FA is less "predictive" and more "explanatory" model - that is, it is less likely for one to make predictions using a FA model (although it does happen sometimes). In most cases (especially within social sciences), FA is used for describing a phenomenon (i.e a latent variable). As far as I know, within the context of LPA the multinomial regression is used for describing the relationships between the output variable(s) and the covariates, as can be seen [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6589011/).